# Can the Dzhanibekov Effect celestial bodies, like Earth’s crust and/or core causing the flipping of magnetic poles?

Tags: magnetic-fields, rotational-dynamics, earth, earthquake

“The tennis racket theorem or intermediate axis theorem, is a kinetic phenomenon of classical mechanics which describes the movement of a rigid body with three distinct principal moments of inertia. It has also dubbed the Dzhanibekov effect, after Soviet cosmonaut Vladimir Dzhanibekov, who noticed one of the theorem's logical consequences whilst in space in 1985. Formally the effect had been known for at least 150 years, having been described by Louis Poinsot in 1834.” - wiki

Would this affect the crust, or is it too spherical and spinning on its primary axis to flip? If not the crust, could it flip the core if it is shaped so that it is rotating on its intermediate axis? Or is the core too close to spherical and rotating around its primary access to cause the core to flip?

I am asking regarding the flipping of the magnetic poles and in regards to the “Noah Myth” in the Bible about a “great flood.”

Answer (score 1):

As you note, Earth is spherical (and already spinning on an axis). So, the three moments of inertia required for the Dzhanibekov Effect are not very distinct. Without some massive additional force suddenly being applied to Earth, it's not going to happen. The Dzhanibekov Effect does apply to some of our neighbours like asteroids and Pluto's moon Nix, for example.

With regard to magnetic pole flipping, geological records suggest this happens with some regularity and since it's a reversible process, it can also come close to happening but then revert. A threat occasioned by pole flipping would be strong solar radiation caused by puncturing of Earth's temporarily weakened magnetic field** by solar flares. Floods, not particularly expected.

You might the link below interesting. In contrast to your question it examines how abrupt sea change levels cause magnetic reversal.

https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1004148

** the weakened protective magnetic field would allow for holes to be made in the ozone layer.

Comment: I’m aware of pole flipping and its effects. I was more interested in what would cause it. Since the core seems to be less spherical, I wondered if the Dzhanibekov Effect would be more possible with the core.

Comment: Consider that the Dzanibekov Effect was first noticeably observed in a wingnut: the object possesses a hollow core, the centre of gravity being significantly shifted along the axis of rotation in comparison to Earth which has a spheroidal solid iron core. The dynamics between the crust-mantle (taking them as one here) molten outer core and solid inner core are complex but there are other factors not mentioned in the answer making the Earth's rotation stable: 1) speed of rotation 2) gravitational stabilisation by the Sun and Moon. We're nowhere near tumbling in space like a wingnut is.